# scroll event not firing on div inside scroll-able div

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a div inside another div where the outer div has a height less than the contents.

the first content has a scroll event

```
 <div style="overflow:auto;height:200px">
  <div (scroll)="scrollHandler($event)">Hello {{name}}</div>

.... Other content elements.
```

but this scroll event is not working. 
please note that I want to trigger scroll event on the element, not on the window.

I have a plunkr here

https://plnkr.co/edit/Ib0fxBIb7syGdEtQ1Rz4

Comment: Write a directive and set hostlistener on scroll

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scroll event handler should be on the outer div, the one that has the scrollbar:

```
<div style="overflow:auto; height:200px" (scroll)="scrollHandler($event)">
  <div>Hello {{name}}</div>
  ...
</div>
```

You can test [this modified plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/fS9sJNitw41z4aS14X8F?p=preview) (check the console, I removed the alert calls).

Comment: but what if i have to write a logic when a particular element reaches top of div while scrolling. let say an element in the list that reaches top of the scroll needs to turn red. 
this way i want to hook on the event of each div in the list.

Comment: You can compare `event.target.scrollTop` to the `offsetTop` of the element, as shown in [this modified plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/8wLQPSkDdW39qxEFYMGk?p=info).